# Does Hibernate automatically generate constraints for unique indexes?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following annotation and in combination with a Spring Boot application, Hibernate takes care of creating the necessary tables and columns currently.

```
@Index(name = "[...]", columnList = "col1,col2", unique = true)
```

Though, I'm migrating to Liquibase and used `generate-changelog` to give me a starting point. Within that changelog, Liquibase generated 1 statement to add an unique constraint with the above name and columns and 1 additional statement to create an unique index with the same name and columns.

```xml
<addUniqueConstraint columnNames="[...]" constraintName="[...]" tableName="[...]"/>
<createIndex indexName="[...]" tableName="[...]" unique="true">
```

From my understanding, a unique constraint should be backed by an unique index under the hood, possibly created automatically by the RDBMS. But I'm not aware of the other way around, if an unique index is created explicitly, that it creates an additional constraint.

**So, is Hibernate creating both even with the index annotation only?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really seems to be Hibernate creating a unique constraint only and relying on the RDBMS creating an additional index implicitly. I would have expected Hibernate issuing a `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` instead, so that both can be handled independently. Non-unique indexes don't require a constraint as well. But 3rd party log corresponding statements:

```
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -
alter table Student add constraint uniqueIndex unique (firstName)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-indexes#4-index-uniqueness

And my own application ONLY logs the following statements as well. There are NO additional index handling statements or stuff for my name of interest, while there are `CREATE INDEX` statements for other, non-unique indexes.

```
alter table ac_costcenter drop constraint [...]
alter table ac_costcenter add constraint [...] unique (col1, col2)
```

Comment: do doubts baeldung is wrong there

Comment: It's not, I can confirm it with increased log level: `alter table ac_costcenter drop constraint AC_Costcenter_UX` + `alter table ac_costcenter add constraint AC_Costcenter_UX unique (company_id, key)` Hibernate doesn't create an index explicitly.

Comment: `@Index` annotation causes JPA provider to create index, that would be weird if it wasn't doing that, wouldn't it? `@UniqueConstraint` and `@Column(unique=true)` cause JPA provider to somehow enforce uniqueness, which could be "expressed" using SQL in different ways (either constraint or unique index) depending of DB vendor, column nullability, whether it is required to enforce uniqueness of column or expression, defferability, etc. DB may create unique index automatically when adding unique constraint.

Comment: That's why I asked the question, but I my logs don't lie. :-) There's no explicit index created and when we would look at the Hibernate code, there surely would be an exception for unique indexes compared to non-unique ones for some reason. In my logs I do have `CREATE INDEX`, but not for the unique ones, only constraints for those.

Comment: Well, I have found that: [createIndexOrUniqueKey](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java#L2134).